# How to read parquet file from s3 using dask with specific AWS profile

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, dask, python-s3fs

How to read a parquet file on s3 using `dask` and specific AWS profile (stored in a credentials file). Dask uses `s3fs` which uses `boto`. This is what I have tried:

```
>>>import os
>>>import s3fs
>>>import boto3
>>>import dask.dataframe as dd

>>>os.environ['AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE'] = "~/.aws/credentials"

>>>fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False,profile_name="some_user_profile")
>>>fs.exists("s3://some.bucket/data/parquet/somefile")
True
>>>df = dd.read_parquet('s3://some.bucket/data/parquet/somefile')
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never mind, that was easy, but did not find any reference online, so here it is:

```
>>>import os
>>>import dask.dataframe as dd
>>>os.environ['AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE'] = "/path/to/credentials"

>>>df = dd.read_parquet('s3://some.bucket/data/parquet/somefile',
                      storage_options={"profile_name":"some_user_profile"})
>>>df.head()
# works
```

Comment: Documentation [here](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html#s3) - please feel free to submit improvements as a PR if you think it could be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for posting both your question and answer online!  Hopefully your efforts help others in the future.

Comment: @mdurant thanks I see it now,  I did skim over that documentation page but missed it :(

Comment: @muon , no problem! We are aware that the docs pages are rather voluminous :)

Comment: this is not working with pd.read_parquet. Getting '''read_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'storage_options'''